# antlr html pcdata

Tags: html-parsing, antlr, antlr3

Im trying to write very simple HTML parser with ANTLR and Im facing problem, that ~ rule which should match all until specified character is not working.

My lexer grammar:

```
lexer grammar HtmlParserLexer;

HTML: OHTML PCDATA CHTML;

PCDATA :(~'<') ; //match all until <

OHTML: '<html>';

CHTML: '</html>';
```

Im trying to match:

```
<html>foo bar</html>
```

Error from Eclipse ANTLR plugin Interpreter:

```
MismatchedTokenException: line 1:7 mismatched input UNKNOW expecting '<'
```

Which means, that my grammar ignore PCDATA rule and I dont know why.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule `PCDATA :(~'<') ;` matches a single character other than `'<'`. You'll need to repeat it once or more: `PCDATA :(~'<')+ ;` (notice the `+`).

You may also want to allow `<html></html>` (nothing in between`<html>` and `</html>`). In that case, you shouldn't change `PCDATA :(~'<')+ ;` into `PCDATA :(~'<')* ;`, but do this instead:

```
HTML: OHTML PCDATA? CHTML;

PCDATA : (~'<')+ ;
```

because you shouldn't create lexer rules that could potentially match an empty string.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. I saw repetition on examples with ~, but I didnt try it. I thought that it will match all until given character without use of repetition...